# Form Submit Listener prevent form submission on IE8

Tags: javascript, forms, google-tag-manager

I have set up Universal Analytics tracking for a website using Google Tag Manager and have had success using the form submission listener to track different form submissions. It came to my attention today that users in IE8 were unable to submit login forms. Login forms are the only native forms on the site, whereas all other forms are added via javascript from Eloqua.

As soon as I disable the form submission listener, IE8 users can log in without issue. Because a user *could* have to log in on an page of the site, I've had to disable all form tracking for now.

Form HTML

```
<form class="login-prompt__form" method="POST">
        <div class="input input--text">
            <input id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="input input--text">
            <input id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
        </div>
        <ul class="button-group">
            <li>
                <button class="btn btn--med" type="submit" formmethod="post" >Log In</button>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/login/recover-password">Forgot password?</a></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Absolutely no javascript errors are generated. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a conflict in another library. Can you post a url?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue with no javascript error.

In our case there is a Google tag manager document level

> document.gtmFormActionFunction()

and there is a also a jquery submitHandler assigned.  We haven't figured out how get these 2 to play nice yet other than removing one of these.

The following article was helpful in identifying the issue.
http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/dont-gtm-listeners-work/

They cite event propagation needs to work up to the document node recommending you replace where appropriate:

> return false;

with

> event.preventDefault();